# How to run PHP in Kubernetes via unix socket?

Tags: docker, cloud, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have nginx and php-fpm containers in Google Container Engine and I would like to run it through unix socket instead of network.

I also have the Google SQL Proxy container and it uses empty volume to provide connection to Google SQL databases through sockets placed on that volume that is shared with other containers. So I was thinking of using the same approach for PHP but it is not working.

I have empty volume of emptyDir type mounted to php and nginx containers. The volume is mounted, I can see it in both containers. But if I try to use nginx I will get (socket)file not found in logs.

I have also added the www-data(same uid as in php container) user into nginx container and set it in nginx conf but it didn't help.

Is Google SQL Proxy special in some way and I have to use network for PHP or am I missing something here?

Comment: Why do you want to use a unix socket?

Comment: You shouldn't use emptyDir, I think. Use hostVolume to mount your unix sockets.

Comment: emptyDir is ok to use as it's available for the lifetime of the deployment pod. Using a hostVolume may create some conflict between pods with the same socket file.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to get the approach you described working. I use a `emptyDir` in a `deployment` so a shared `/sock` folder is mounted to both nginx and fpm:

```
  - name: fpm
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: php-socket
      mountPath: /sock
    ...

  - name: nginx
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: php-socket
      mountPath: /sock
    ...

  volumes:
  - name: php-socket
    emptyDir: {}
```

I found this article helpful for the actual nginx and fpm configuration: https://medium.com/@shrikeh/setting-up-nginx-and-php-fpm-in-docker-with-unix-sockets-6fdfbdc19f91

The snag I hit was a file in my php-fpm docker container config called `zz-docker.conf` which contains `listen = [::]:9000`. Since the name of the file is alphabetically high, it was clobbering my other config file, stopping the unix socket communication working (i.e. `listen = /sock/php.sock`). I removed the problem line using this in the `Dockerfile`:

```
sed -i -e ‘/listen/d’ /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf
```

Comment: I did the same, but Im having permission problems - if i don't chmod /sock and the socket file 777, Apache is denied permission. Apache is running with user www-data in its config, as well as php-fpm. It feels like different www-data users in different containers may be getting treated as separate users instead of one user inside the pod maybe. How did you get around this situation? What's the users of your nginx and php-fpm and the permissions of the socket?

Comment: We're using docker images based off of the official images of nginx and fpm. Specifically we're using `nginx:1.14-alpine` and `FROM php:7.4.23-fpm`. These docker images use linux users called `nginx` and `www-data` respectively. We are not using Apache.

Comment: Yes, I noted that. But the question that different users pose is the same: How do nginx and www-data users in different containers share ownership of the shared volume? Did you put 777 as permissions on the volume? Or did you set security context for containers etc. The solution I found was to set the ownership to www-data and make the volume world-readable. Only www-data can write and apache (or nginx) can read.

Comment: I checked the permissions of our `/sock` folder and it is `drwxrwxrwx` and the permissions of our socket file (`/sock/sock.php`) is `srw-rw-rw-`. The permissions of the socket file come from our php config (`/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` where we set `listen.owner = www-data` and `listen.group = www-data` and `listen.mode = 0666`. We did not explicitly set any permissions on the volume, or `/sock` folder or set any security context for the containers. I agree, our setup ranks poor for security! Bringing it to my attention is helpful, thank you! Some of our write permissions are unneeded.